# Can't read user data from Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm developing an Android app in Java using Firebase.
The app has 2 tasks that need user data. So, when I click on the first button, it work, but when I restart the app and I click on the second button (same code), it not work.
[app's image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWmk1.png)

First button's code:

```
if(mAuth.getCurrentUser() == null) {
        accessoFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), accessoFragment.getTag());
    }

    if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
        prelevaDati();

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().
                add(R.id.fragmentContainerView, ProfiloFragment.class, null).commit();

        toolbar.setSubtitle("Profilo");
}
```

Second button's code:

```
case R.id.buttonScheda:
            if(mAuth.getCurrentUser() == null) {
            accessoFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), accessoFragment.getTag());
        }

            if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
                prelevaDati();
                toolbar.setSubtitle("SCHEDA");
                child = "Scheda";
            } else return;

            break;
```

Read data function:

```
public void prelevaDati() {
    mDatabase.child("Utenti").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            utente = snapshot.getValue(Utente.class);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) { }
    });
}
```

Help me please

Question updated thanks to @FrankvanPuffelen:
The object user is null after pressed the second button because the onDataChange and onCancelled functions are skipped. So, when I try to use user methods, the program stop running and show a NullPointException in the console:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.HashMap com.example.app.Utente.getScheda()' on a null object reference

Comment: 1) What does "it not work" mean here? I.e. when you set a breakpoint on each line, and then run the code in a debugger, which is the first line that doesn't do what you expect it to do? What are all the variables used on that line? 2) Never leave `onCancelled` empty, as you're ignoring errors. At its minimum it should be: `public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { throw databaseError.toException(); }`

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank van Puffelen asked for, and please also responded with @.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen question updated

Comment: I don't see any calls to the `getScheda` method in the code that you shared. Are you sure that error is coming from this code?

Comment: The error is coming from another class, but in the debug I see that the problem is in the listener because the program skip it and I can see that user is null. So I sull’ send in the class a null object.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen addListenerForSingleValueEvent is async, right? So maybe this is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I resolved the problem.

The problem was that the second button was in a switch, so I don't know why, but addValueEventListener not work in switchs. So I placed the listener in a onClickListener in the onViewCreated (in his fragment).

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    view.findViewById(R.id.buttonScheda).setOnClickListener(v -> {
        if(mAuth.getCurrentUser() == null) {
            accessoFragment.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), accessoFragment.getTag());
        }

        if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
            mDatabase.child(mAuth.getUid()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    utente = snapshot.getValue(Utente.class);
                    toListaFragment();
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                    Log.d("DatabaseError", error.getDetails());
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).